# 07 Suzuki Boulevard S40 will not start without being connected to jump leads

Tags: starter

My 07 Suzuki Boulevard S40 will not turn on no power whatsoever with the key on but if you hook cables to it it will fire up but if you remove the cables it does what do you think that could be please help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the condition of your battery?

Comment: Top post batteries can become coated with a hard non-conductive layer of oxide. The terminal screw can be tight, but very little current will pass in or out of the battery. Use a battery brush with a blade scraper to clean the posts and the cable faces.

Comment: I fixed the bike actually and thankfully lol! Me and my home boy dug into it today, and I decided to rebuild the carb another issue with the bike when I got it N they had it azz backwards we slapped everything back in N we tried it and lights came on and she was alive Mo power bby fixed it and love the bike so much super fast 650